# Remove RichTextBox line by duplicated string

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to remove all lines which has the same text string.
For example filtered string is "MyString". If "MyString" appear more than once in RhichTextBox, just remove whole text line from RichTextBox. So there will be just a line where "MyString" first appeared. All other lines with the same string will be removed.

Here is what I have tried:

```
    Dim myfilteredstring As String
    myfilteredstring = "MyString"
    Dim rtblines As New List(Of String)(RichTextBox1.Lines)
    Dim Line1 As String
    Dim Line2 As String

    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
        Line1 = RichTextBox1.Lines(j).ToString

        Dim k As Integer
        For k = 0 To RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1
            Line2 = RichTextBox1.Lines(k).ToString

            If Line1.Contains(myfilteredstring) Then
                If Line2.Contains(myfilteredstring) Then
                    rtblines.Remove(Line2)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: In the inner For loop, you need to start `k` at `j + 1`  to avoid trying to delete the line with the first concurrence of `myfilteredstring`. `For k = j + 1 to RichTextBox1.Lines.Count - 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. The code gets the index of the first occurrence. Then works backwards through your list to the line after the first occurrence and deletes them. and replaces the contents of the RTB with your updated list of lines.

```
    Dim myfilteredstring As String
    myfilteredstring = "MyString"
    Dim rtblines As New List(Of String)(RichTextBox1.Lines)

    Dim firstlineFound As Boolean = False

    Dim indexOfFirstLine As Integer = -1
    For i As Integer = 0 To rtblines.Count - 1
        If rtblines(i).Contains(myfilteredstring) Then
            indexOfFirstLine = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    For i As Integer = rtblines.Count - 1 To indexOfFirstLine + 1 Step -1
        If rtblines(i).Contains(myfilteredstring) Then
            rtblines.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next
    RichTextBox1.Lines = rtblines.ToArray
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you want to do. This will remove any line contains `MyString`

```
Dim firstAppearance As String = RichTextBox1.Lines.Where(Function(line As String) line.Contains("MyString")).First()
RichTextBox1.Lines = RichTextBox1.Lines.Where(Function(line As String) (Not line.Contains("MyString")) OrElse (line = firstAppearance)).ToArray()
```

Comment: This will remove also the first line on the Lines collection

Comment: Not my downvote but I don't think that this will work either. Let me test it